# If I get a paper copy of my license from the DMV can I use that for a proof of ID at the border to get back into the U.S. from Mexico?

Tags: usa, international-travel

I lost my license and went to the DMV but got a paper copy and I'm leaving to Mexico in two days. I won't get the actual ID for another week. Is it still valid to use when coming back into the U.S. from Mexico.

Comment: A driver's license is not usually sufficient to cross an international border.  You typically need a passport.  In some cases you can use another document to prove your nationality instead of a passport.  Depending on your nationality, you may also need to present evidence of your immigration status.  Are you a US citizen?  If not, what is your nationality and what is your immigration status in the US?

Comment: If you are not a Mexican national, legally you are required to hold a passport to enter Mexico (whether they ask to see it or not)

Comment: @phoog: for land or sea entry to US from other 'WHTI' countries -- Canada, Mexico, and 'the Caribbean' which apparently is actually Bermuda -- an [_enhanced_ driver's license (or nondriver ID)_](https://www.dhs.gov/enhanced-drivers-licenses-what-are-they) issued by a few states is accepted (as equivalent to a Fed-issued passport card). But they need antitamper/antiforgery features, so a paper copy won't be enough -- officially. Actually US citizens must be admitted even without doc, but CBP can take a while to _verify_ that citizenship.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 right, that's why I said "in some cases" and asked about status.  Enhanced licenses are issued only by 5 states on the Canadian border.  The question doesn't even specify the means of travel.  I'm voting to close as needing detail.

Comment: Not directly related, but TSA will accept an expired US D/L as valid ID under some conditions (but **not** a temporary D/L), but unless you find yours in the meantime that’s not of much help.

Comment: How are you going to Mexico and back? Flying it via the land border? Are you a US and/or Mexican citizen? What state issued your license? What other ID to you have? In general, travelling between the US and Mexico, in both directions, requires a passport, not just a driver’s license, because they need proof of citizenship, not just proof of identity.

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming that you are a U.S. citizen. If you are not a U.S. citizen, you must show proof that you have the legal right to live in the U.S. whenever you are crossing the border.

If you are a U.S. citizen, you must show proof of U.S. citizenship when you enter the U.S. from Mexico.

If you fly from Mexico to the U.S., you must have a U.S. passport to board the plane. You cannot use your paper driver's license at the airport in Mexico.

If you are crossing by land from Mexico into the U.S., you must show proof of U.S. citizenship. Showing a U.S. passport is the fastest way to enter the U.S. If you don't have a U.S. passport, the border officers (also known as CBP) will take more time to verify you are a U.S. citizen. Showing a U.S. birth certificate, certificate of naturalization, or other proof of U.S. citizenship will shorten your wait time at the border. Your paper driver's license might prove your identity, but it won't prove that you are a U.S. citizen.

You can get an emergency passport if you don't have one at the local U.S. embassy or consulate if you are in Mexico.

You can apply to get a U.S. passport quickly through the State Department if you are still in the U.S. Their `travel.state.gov` website explains the process in more detail.

TLDR: Get a U.S. passport before you travel abroad. It makes travel easier.